# Backup uSD card into smallest img/zip file

Tags: backup, gparted, dd, micro-sd

I want to backup my self-made RPI based mp3-player.
There is a 16GB uSD card inside, with only 4GB of data used.
When i use dd to copy the whole uSD card as backup, I get a 16GB img file.
zipping it gives ~8GB.

Do you know a way to "zero" all data on the uSD, which is not used, so that the zip gets more efficient?

Alternatively, I might reduce the size of the partition using gparted, but this sounds somehow complex to me (I don't know how much space is needed for tmp-files, etc.)

Comment: Clonezilla has different levels of compression. The maximum should give the same result as Zip or even smaller. Of course, the speed is inversely proportional to the compression level. Result is *.img

Comment: I would add that Clonezilla is smart enough to only copy the used blocks, which makes the process faster than crude cloning and works without zeroing out the free blocks. A Clonezilla image is a directory with several files (where the big files are compressed).

Answer (score 0):

If the file system is ext2, ext3, or ext4 then you might consider using [zerofree](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/zerofree.8.html) to fill the unallocated blocks with zeros.

For example the command for an **unmounted** ext2/3/4 file system on partition /dev/sdf1 would be:

```
sudo zerofree /dev/sdf1
```

Answer (score 0):

I used "zerofill" for vfat as follows:
Mount uSD card, than go to the root-folder:

> cd mntpoint

Fill empty space with zeros:

> sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=tmp-file 
>   rm tmp-file

Do backup into img-file

> sudo dd if=/dev/sde of=mybackup.img bs=32M 
>   tar -cvzf mybackup.tgz mybackup.img

In my example, the filesize before stripping the sd-card was: 8860766726
and after: 2552202816
Note: This method writes the whole unused memory of the micro SD, which degrades the lifetime!